# How to hide a folder in C:\Program Files without turning off .exe program in it?

Tags: windows-10, process, lock, files-folders

In `C:\Program Files` folder there are multiple folders containing drivers and .exe files for computer programs. I would like to know whether it is possible to hide a folder (let's say Discord) and all of its content without forcing the `.exe` program to be turned off (`Discord.exe` can still be opened).

I've tied multiple folder locking systems, such as Wise Folder Hider to name a few, that perfectly hides and hinders folder location entirely but it also kills the program itself.

I look forward to any insights into this issue and I hope it is a solvable one.

Comment: In order to run a program you need to be able to see it. If you can't see it in any way at all then you cannot run it. This feels a bit like an XY problem. Are you trying to block other users from seeing or using the program or is there some reason you need to "hide" it? If you want to hide it from other (non administrator) users then you could simply install it to your personal user profile, when they log in then the will not be able to find it.

Comment: Actually, the only user of the laptop is only me. I am trying to hide program called FocusMe from myself so I couldn't kill it while it is running. Maybe it would be plausible to make folder invisible but accessible by the system?

Comment: As an Administrator you can easily and without any effort disable any suggestions we could provide.

Comment: Could you still provide any of them, even if they can me overcome? I'd like to hinder the path even a little bit

Comment: I have to agree with Ramhound here, this is a self-control issue and programs can *help* poke you in certain directions but are by no means a substitute as anything you can set up you can easily undo. You might want to set up a "low access" user with parental controls for when you need a little control, but again as *you* are the problem overcoming it is as simple as entering a password which is the same as pretty much any other way to do it. This is a *you* problem, not really a *computer* problem.

Comment: `containing drivers and .exe files` .. err.. WHAT drivers are stored in Program Files?

Comment: FocusMe is a paid app.  Let their developers figure this out from the logistics end rather than you having to figure it out from the "hacky s**ty workaround" end.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Some manufacturer driver update tools use the Program Files directory to put their files and drivers prior to poking the system to install them. It can make it easier for a user to find them in order to reinstall factory drivers after updates as well. In particular the [Surface Pro drivers](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=100419) from Microsoft do this. I wouldn't want to mess around there permanently with auto-updaters, but for "factory driver packs" it seems at least condoned by Microsoft. Intel DSA also downloads driver to that area.

Comment: Thanks for the lesson @Mokubai.  Bad form as far as windows standards.. but even Microsoft doesn't follow their own rules anymore.  Thanks again.  Nobody wants to be ignorant.. especially me.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Windows has "standards"? Since when?!?! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Make the folder as hidden in folder properties as shown below
[image]

And then disable "hidden items" checkbox in view tab as shown below:

[image]

Comment: Already done that, it kills the program after the computer reboot.

Comment: @WannaAsk777 - Add the application to the list of applications that automatically start.

Answer (score 0):

Simple idea: Rename `FocusMe.exe` that you intend hiding to the
same name as that of some program that you would be afraid to terminate.

An example is `csrss.exe`, which is an essential part of Windows.
If you kill the wrong `csrss.exe`, Windows will shut down immediately.

Another example is `svchost.exe` which hosts the Windows system services.

Still another example is whatever program you are using the most
during the day.
This can be your browser, development tool, or whatever.